# How to find aws IoT button mac address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am trying to find out the amazon IoT button's mac address to connect it with my working place network. But I do not know the process about how to get it. Could somebody give me the instruction or any helpful link about this matter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was actually not a difficult task. At first, I need to connect to a network. When it will be connected, my Netgear wifi router is showing me that it is connected to the network. And from the router, it is easy to get the mac address for my button.